# Retrieving data from hosted azure cloud service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, azure

I am trying to retrieve records from an online azure cloud service I have hosted but I am getting this error when I try retrieve a number of records. But when I test it with a single record i get no error.

Here is the error I am getting:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

    client.Open();

    ServiceReference1.TrackList List = new ServiceReference1.TrackList();
    List = client.SearchTrackByAuthComp(10000015);

    foreach (var item in List.Trax)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
    }

    //Console.WriteLine(hold);
    Console.ReadKey();

    client.Close();


}

public static TrackList SearchTrackByAuthComp(int intAuthCompID)
{
    SamroEntitiesV2 Context = new SamroEntitiesV2();
    TrackList Traks = new TrackList();

    try
    {
        Traks.Trax = Context.Tracks.Where(x => x.CompAuthID.Equals(intAuthCompID)).ToList();
        Traks.OperationStatus.Status = true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Traks.OperationStatus.Status = false;
    }
    return Traks;
}
public class TrackList : BaseEntity
{
    public List<Tracks> Trax { get; set; }

    public TrackList()
    {
        if (Trax == null)
            Trax = new List<Tracks>();
    }
}

public class OperationStatus
{
    public bool Status { set; get; }
}

public class BaseEntity
{
    public OperationStatus OperationStatus { set; get; }

    public BaseEntity()
    {
        if (OperationStatus == null)
        OperationStatus = new OperationStatus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the code work locally. It sounds to me like your search is failing and throwing a 500 error.

Comment: Showing us the SearchTrackByAuthComp function and TrackList class could also help understand better

Comment: Yes It works perfectly locally @ChrisBint and TrackList class is a class that has a join I made for object. Here is my function and class.

Comment: I edited my code with the class updates.

Comment: Please check your App.config file and check that the IP used is pointing to the same IP your cloud service is using (entries within the system.servicemodel section). I have experienced problems seeing the entries containing different IP's after generating the service-client using VS. If that is the case, switch on "show all files" in Solution Explorer and try to find all entries of this IP (the wrong one)in the files contained in the Service_References folder and replace them with the right one.